Docker Container in Windows Image not able to Start DB2 Server
I have built a Docker Image, with Windows Server 2019 as the Base.
Docker file also installs DB2 10.5 Database server.
The problem is, the DB2 Server instance Service is not getting started.
It is in "Stopped" state. If I start the service via PowerShell, I'm getting the below Error alert.
"Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start"
When I examined, the service with the display name "Service" and with the Name "Lanmanserver", is in "Stopped" state. DB2 Service is Dependent on this service. Since this service is stopped, DB2 is not getting started.
If I try to start "Lanmanserver", I'm getting the same error,
"Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start"
When I checked, Lanmanserver is dependent on SMB adapter, which is "Disabled" by default in a Windows Container Instance.
If anyone could help me build and run a Docker Image with Windows Server as the base, and also to get DB2 database server installed successfully.

This is not a programming question. It is a configuration question. It is nothing to do with Db2 per se, because if Db2 has a dependency on the lanman server-component being available in the container, then your real problem is to get that containerised lanman server working first. Separately, Db2-LUW does not require a Windows-Server, it will also run on a Windows-Workstation (with some limitations on capacity, #connections etc)

I would use use one of the preexisting DB2 images, instead of building my own.

@TheImpaler IBM DB2 Image is not getting added into the windows image.
DockerFile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
FROM icr.io/db2_community/db2
Docker BUILD - Output:
Step 2/2 : FROM icr.io/db2_community/db2
latest: Pulling from db2_community/db2
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries

I have never tried running docker in Windows, so I have no opinion on it. The Db2 linux docker image works out of the box for me, though.

My requirement is, we are building a .Net Application in Visual Studio, and the Database of the application is DB2. So we have to have a Windows Container, to build the .Net App, and also a DB2 Server needs to be present. Because the build requires DB2 Server, while it was trying to build few DLLs, without DB2, the build will fail. Is there any ways to have a Windows Container, with DB2 in it.
